# Equivalent of Excel Solver in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

EDIT: I have edited my question to be more specific as horchler's comment helped get me started.

I have data in excel which I am using to make an optimization analysis. In excel, using the solver, it's easy:  I can choose a cell with a formula then pick the cells i need to change and add constraints and then minimize.  But, I'm lost when it comes to Matlab's optimization process.  The documentation appears to only provide examples of optimization problems that analyze simple one-line functions like f(x) = -(x1)(x2)(x3).  I am unable to figure out how to apply these examples in my own case.

The function I am trying to maximize is relatively complex.  As inputs, it takes on a number of scalar variables as well as multiple structures that contain data that is used in the calculations.

My issue is that I am trying to maximize the value of the function by altering three scalar variables, while leaving the other input variables constant (since they are data).  More specifically, my function looks something like:

```
function x = NameOfFunction (w1, w2, w3, a, b, c, Structure1, Structure2, Structure3)
```

I would like to maximize x by changing only variables w1, w2, and w3.  In other words, I would like for Matlab to tell me the values of w1, w2, and w3 that maximize x, while leaving all the other variables alone.  Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the Syms toolbox? You'll know if "syms a" doesn't return an error.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=matlab+optimization+tutorial

Comment: Your question isn't very specific with regards to what you need to do. If you need to apply inequality constraints (and other types), have you looked at [`fmincon`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html)? It works very much like Excel's solver. What do you mean by your problems being data-driven? Pretty much all optimization routines boil down to a single objective function that returns a scalar (you are trying to find a single max or min or root after all). Internally, however, your objective function can be arbitrarily complex and evaluate multiple functions that are combined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Without Constraints

You will probably end up finding the solution with [`fmincon`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html) or [`fminunc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fminunc.html) in MATLAB. For example, using `fminunc` because its syntax is a little less cluttered, you could start by defining your cost function in a separate file, named "NameOfFunction.m":

```
function cost = NameOfFunction(w, a, b, c, Structure1, Structure2, Structure3)
% Your code goes here, just remember that you return a scalar-valued cost from
% this function.
```

Note that `fminunc` and similar will try to minimize this cost function. If you need to maximize it, then just multiply your final cost by `-1` at the end. Next, you create a handle to your function in your main file:

```
h = @(w)NameOfFunction(w, a, b, c, Structure1, Structure2, Structure3);
```

Where `w` is a vector of the variables that you want to optimize:

```
w = [w1, w2, w3];
```

This basically masks your function with all of its inputs as just a function of what you want to optimize, `w`, as far as `fminunc` is concerned. This allows you to pass your parameters `a`, `b`, `c`, `Structure`, `Structure2`, and `Structure3`to your cost function `NameOfFunction` without `fminunc` touching them. You can now call `fminunc` on your handle with an initial guess for your vector `w`:

```
w0 = [w1_init, w2_init, w3_init];
[w, fval] = fminunc(h, w0);
```

And `fminunc` should find the optimal values for your `w` vector that minimize (note, it looks for the minimum) your cost function.

### With constraints

In this case you would use `fmincon` most likely. If your constraints are in the forms of upper and lower bounds on each of your parameters that you are optimizing, then put them in to vectors:

```
ub = [w1_upper, w2_upper, w3_upper];
lb = [w1_lower, w2_lower, w3_lower];
```

And call the same handle as before using `fmincon`:

```
[w, fval] = fmincon(h, w0, [], [], [], [], lb, ub);
```

The four `[]`s in the above are just placeholders for parameters that you are not using. `fmincon` can handle more complex constraints too; check out the documentation (linked at the start of this discussion) for more details.